# Scala XML attribute replacement results in appending modified node as a child

Tags: xml, scala, scala-xml

Im trying to write an XML parsing utility that allows a user to modify an XML attribute through providing an attribute name, the current attribute value and the new value they would like the attribute to have. 
Here is my code:

```
def main (args: Array[String]) {
   val xml= <Rule debug="true" expression="testing"/>
   val printable= replaceXMLEntryAttribute(xml, "debug", "true", "false")
   println(printable)
}
/**
   * This method is used to iterate over the entirety of the xml presented and modify the XML attribute desired 
   */
  def replaceXMLEntryAttribute(elem: Elem, attrName: String, curVal: String, desiredVal: String): Elem = {

    def replace(current: Elem): Elem = current.copy(
      child = current.map {
        case e: Elem if isReplacementEntry(current, attrName, curVal) ⇒ generateReplacementXMLAttribute(current)
        case e: Elem ⇒ replace(e)
        case other⇒ other
      }
    )

   def generateReplacementXMLAttribute(node: Elem): Elem = {
      val currentXML= node.toString()
      val newAttr= currentXML.replace(curVal, desiredVal)
      return XML.loadString(newAttr)
    }
    replace(elem)
  }

  private def isReplacementEntry(node: Elem, attributeName: String,  currentAttrValue: String): Boolean = {
   val attr = "@" + attributeName
   val exists = node \\ attr find { _.text == currentAttrValue }
   exists match{
     case None => false
     case _ => true
   }
```

The desired output is `<Rule debug="false" expression="testing"/>`
while the result of the program is `<Rule debug="true" expression="testing"><Rule expression="testing" debug="false"/></Rule>`

I can only guess and say the replace method is messing up here.

Comment: So after significant testing, I've found that it is indeed the replace method messing up here (specifically the current.map part of it). Any advice would be fantastic

Comment: Worst case scenario might migrate this project to scales xml

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation of the [`Elem.map`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.7/scala-xml/index.html#scala.xml.Elem@map[B,That](f:A=>B)(implicitbf:scala.collection.generic.CanBuildFrom[Repr,B,That]):That) method doesn't have any text to explain what it is supposed to do, and its type is confusing. To obtain a more concrete type, we can use the Scala interpreter:

```
scala> import scala.xml._
scala> val elem: Elem = <numbers><one/><two/><three/></numbers>
scala> :t elem.map(identity)
scala.xml.NodeSeq
```

Strange, why would it produce a `NodeSeq`? If `Elem.map` was mapping over the element's children, returning an `Elem` with the same label and attributes but new children, the return type should be `Elem`, not `NodeSeq`. To verify whether `Elem.map` is really iterating over its children, let's accumulate the nodes we encounter into a list.

```
scala> var nodes = Seq[Node]()
scala> elem.map {node =>
     |   nodes :+= node
     |   node
     | }
res: scala.xml.NodeSeq = NodeSeq(<numbers><one/><two/><three/></numbers>)
scala> nodes
res: Seq[scala.xml.Node] = List(<numbers><one/><two/><three/></numbers>)
```

If we were iterating over the children, I would have expected `List(<one/>, <two/>, <three/>)`, but that's not what we got. So it seems we are iterating over a 1-element collection containing the element itself, which isn't very useful. Looking at [the code](https://github.com/scala/scala-xml/blob/master/src/main/scala/scala/xml/Node.scala#L157), however, this seems to be intentional: `Node`, and by extension `Elem`, is a subclass of `NodeSeq` whose sequence consists of a single element, itself.

So, to summarize, the reason you get your unexpected result is that you start with `<Rule debug="true" expression="testing"/>`, you then map over it to obtain the result `<Rule debug="true" expression="testing"/>`, and then you replace the children of Rule with that result, obtaining `<Rule debug="true" expression="testing"><Rule expression="testing" debug="false"/></Rule>`.

The solution to that part of the problem is to use `current.child.map` instead of `current.map`. However, since you are only examining Rule's zero children and not Rule itself, the body of the map is never executed, so the debug attribute is left unchanged. I advise swapping the pattern-matching and the map:

```
def replace: Node => Node =
  {
    case e: Elem if isReplacementEntry(e, attrName, curVal) ⇒ generateReplacementXMLAttribute(e)
    case e: Elem ⇒ e.copy(
      child = e.child.map { replace(_) }
    )
    case other⇒ other
  }
```

After fixing the types to work with `Node`s instead of `Elem`s, I obtain the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

Check my library Advxml on github to replace and edit xml documents!

https://github.com/geirolz/advxml

Example:

```
import com.github.geirolz.advxml.all._
import scala.xml._
import scala.util._

//import MonadError instance for Try
import cats.instances.try_._

val doc: Elem = 
<Persons>
  <Person Name="Mimmo">
    <Cars>
      <Car Brand="Fiat"/>
    </Cars>
  </Person>
</Persons>

val rule: XmlRule = $(_ \ "Person" \ "Cars")
    ==> Replace(<Cars><Car Brand="Lamborghini"/></Cars>)

val result: Try[NodeSeq] = doc.transform[Try](rule)
```